# VPS - Server goes randomly down with gap in all logs

Tags: centos, vps, apache-2.4

We're running several (leased) dedicated servers at a provider in The Netherlands. Everything runs smoothly and most of our virtual servers have a high uptime (99,99%). Except for one server, which is a pain in the ass for us.

It's a webserver with the following specifications:

```
CentOS Linux release 7.0.1406 (Core)
Kernel 3.10.0-123.el7.x86_64

Apache/2.4.12 with mod_ruid2
PHP 5.4.38 (cli)
mysql Ver 15.1 Distrib 5.5.41-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1

All compiled by DirectAdmin 1.48.3
```

Last night, for the second time in a month, our monitoring indicated that the server wasn't reachable via ping or HTTP. This happened at 04.10. Due to an outage at our VoIP provider, we were informed only a hour later, which would give me some interesting information later on.

When I checked, the server was indeed down, there was no connection possible whatsoever. I logged in at the controlpanel of our provider and tried to reach the VPS by opening the console, but I only got an error message: Connection Refused. Next step: sending a reboot signal to the VPS through the controlpanel of our prodiver. After waiting a couple of minutes, there was still no connection possible. I tried rebooting again, but it didn't do anything. I didn't want to wait any longer and called in the last resort: a forced reboot of the VPS (shutting it down the hard way, then boot it again). After that, the server immediately got back up, at 05.15.

I logged in at the server to open up the `messages` log. There I found normal log rules up to 04.10. Then there was a gap, until 05.15. The server didn't had any log rules between the time of going down and the time of going up again. I checked all the other logs: exim, apaches access and error logs, maillogs, etc. but every log file had exactly the same gap: between 04.10 and 05.15.

Some other things I noticed:

- DirectAdmin create system messages in a file called /usr/local/directadmin/data/admin/tickets.list. After rebooting the server, all tickets prior to 05.15 were gone. This is very strange, since deleting the tickets upon reboot or shutdown is not normal behavior.
- Directadmin checks, via a cronjob, every minute for bruteforce attacks in the server logs. It creates a system message every minute if it detects a bruteforce attack in the last minute. Normally, one or two IP-addresses are mentioned in a message. When the server came up again, there was a message created immediately with 25+ IP-addresses. This might be meaningless, but I don't understand it. It would mean that the cronjob stopped working before the server went down, or it would mean that the server registred brute-force attacks when it was down (and the cronjob didn't run at that time). Both scenarios doesn't make any sense. I figured I had to mention it, since it is one of the very few things that I can notice.
- According to our monitoring, there was no significant increase in CPU, memory, I/O or latency, prior to the downtime.

For the first in a long time, I have absolutely no clue about where to look for the cause of the downtime. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: With VPS, the first thing to check is the health of the hosting server.  What does the provider have to say about that?

Comment: I send them an e-mail this morning, still waiting for there response. What could be the problem at their end? All the other virtual servers on the same dedicated server are working fine.

Comment: Similar symptoms could be seen on a physical machine if it somehow lost connectivity with the storage system. The kernel can keep running and respond to pings. But any user mode process will die the first time it need to load data from a memory mapped file or from swap. You may be able to connect to listening TCP ports, but doing so may cause the listening server process to die. After that the kernel will produce connection resets on that TCP port.

Comment: @kasperd, hmm, is there anyway to verify if this is the cause of our problems? And if it is, shouldn't the other virtual servers on the same machine be affected too?

Comment: @MadHatter forgot to mention you in my previous comment, sorry :-).

Comment: @BlueCola If the physical machine had lost connectivity with its storage, you would likely have seen all the virtual machines drop of the network entirely (i.e. not even send you a TCP reset when trying to connect), and the physical machine would need rebooting. Depending on the exact virtualization infrastructure it may be possible for the connectivity between a single VPS and its storage to disappear. More information about the infrastructure would be needed to answer that question in more detail.

Comment: @BlueCola It may be worth looking into netconsole. The problem you are facing most likely triggers some error messages in the kernel log. But by the time it happens there is no longer any way to write those to the storage on that VPS. If you can get that VPS to log through netconsole there is a fair chance of finding out what error the kernel experienced.

Comment: @Kasperd, never heard of netconsole, seems like a perfect solution to debug this problem. I just installed and configured it, I'm very curious what we'll find (but this can take a couple of weeks). Thanks for your help!